# Webservice to get WSO2 Business Process Server workflow view

Tags: wso2, business-process-management

We are currently looking for alternatives to IBM BPM to generate/manage workflows into our application, and we are trying to implement a simple prototype that does some of the same things that IBM BPM does.

So I'm wondering if WSO2 BPS allows us to invoke a WS (either in REST or SOAP) to get the a task view? In IBM BPM we create the HTML that we want to show the user for a specific task, and then we call a WS to get it's corresponding HTML, so that we can embed it into our application.

Is this possible with WSO2 Business Process Server workflow or am I comparing two different league products?

Answer (score -1):

Did you check BonitaSoft for that ? It's an Open Source BPM, which allow to build your own HTML form (if you needed it), directly in HTML and/or in CSS, and call call WS when you like via some standard connector (or by your onw connector if you like to develop it).

And it's a full BPMN 2.0 tool !